# Inserting datas for a specified date range in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

Please lemme know , how to add datas for all days in an year or more in django. Let's say i want to add a vechicle which is available for all days. How can i store this in mysql?, Later whenever search for that vehicles, it should display , AVAILABLE ON EVERYDAY!. I think you guys understand the question! Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: SO isn't a coding service. Please show us what you've tried, where you got stuck, which errors you see. And do some research first. If you look for how to store a date range in django I'm sure you'll find examples. Read [ask] to understand what makes a good question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take boolean field of Django model and if the vehicle is for all days then you have to save True in that Django model field otherwise it will store false.

When you get the data from sql and you will get True value of that field then that vehicle is available for all days.